# Поиск и замена по регулярным выражениям в notepad++

Tags: регулярные-выражения, search, php

Доброго дня. Столкунлся с проблемой, надо заменить все значения

```
real_string($request);
```

на

```
$request
```

Пользуюсь NotePad++, и там есть так называемый поиск по регуляркам. Но как не пробовал, ни чего не выходило. Не могли бы помочь с регуляркой поиска и замены?

Comment: Наконец-то! О регулярках говорят отдельно от HTML! ^-^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты наверно заключаешь регулярку в begin-end? Не, не так надо. Вот нужная тебе регулярка:

```
real_string\((\$[a-z0-9_]*)\)
```

заменить на:

```
\1
```

Здесь принцип почти тот же, что и в PCRE, просто не нужно указывать границы. Единственный доступный модификатор вынесен в виде чекбокса «Учитывать регистр».

Перед заменой советую сначала пометить подстроки на соответствующей вкладке, и только после этого производить замену.

Comment: Для универсальности лучше сделать так:  

    real_string\(([^\)]*)\)
чтобы включить такие вызовы:  

    real_string("text")
или  

    real_string( $request )

Answer (score 0):

Отличный редактор. Поэтому помогу.

Курсор надо поставить на самый верх документа. И вписать код
в поле *найти*:

```
real_string[(][$]request[)]
```

В поле *заменить*

```
$request
```

Comment: Интересный стиль вместо экранирования делать символьные классы, но мне кажется, что Ваш ответ не требует механизма регулярных выражений, так как подобная замена может быть произведена обычным строковым поиском и заменой.

Comment: Ну тогда вот так будет лучше: Вдруг внутри круглых скобок будет комментарий с закрывающей круглой скобкой.

    real_string[  ]*[(]+[ $]+request[^;]+[ ;]